# WSMQ Queue Limit

Tags: java, jms, messaging, ibm-mq

is there a limit on how many queues I can have open within a single connection and single session?  I can currently open up 128 queues and send messages to them.  If I try to open up 129 I get the following error...

Thanks

Error:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedResourceAllocationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'TestQueue_129'. JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:579)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:219)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1000)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:956)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:59)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.initialise(WMQMessageProducer.java:727)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.<init>(WMQMessageProducer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createProducer(WMQSession.java:783)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createSender(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createSender(MQQueueSession.java:147)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createProducer(MQQueueSession.java:248)
    at MyQueue.<init>(MyQueue.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.createContainerAndLaunchApp(launchClient.java:788)
    at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.main(launchClient.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:330)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:108)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2017' ('MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:206)
    ... 39 more
WSCL0100E: Exception received: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.createContainerAndLaunchApp(launchClient.java:788)
    at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.main(launchClient.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:330)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:108)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyQueue.sendMessage(MyQueue.java:39)
    at Main.main(Main.java:55)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Any information or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is controlled by the queue manager's [`MAXHANDS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_qmanager.htm) attribute.

The default is 256.  Depending on how you access the queues, the classes may be opening each one twice, resulting in 128 max open queues.

You can display the queue handles in runmqsc with the [`DIS QSTATUS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086260_.htm) command.